# tinymce saving html tags in database

Tags: javascript, php, database, tinymce

I'm using tinymce in a project and the content saving html tags in database after using this code:

```
tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      entity_encoding : "raw"
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Ummmm - it's a WYSIWYG editor... working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

It working perfectly. It has to save the data with HTML tags so as to maintain the formatting.
But while showing it to user, you need to show the raw data.. for example:

<%= raw @article.article %>
I am just adding **raw** keyword to make everything following it, to be rendered as raw html content without tags.